# How to get the first tile overlay google maps js

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Google Maps SDK to show a map on my site. In addition, I'm showing some custom pins using tiles overlays -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay .

I'm inserting an overlay like this:

```js
const tileAdaptor = new SomeAdaptor();
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, tileAdaptor);
```

And now, from other part of my code, I want to access that same instance. I was doing it like this:

```js
window.map.overlayMapTypes.je[0];
```

But, surprisingly, the `.je` attribute has been renamed! I do not know if that's because it's an internal API or something like that. Now it has been renamed to `.td`.

So, my question is, is there a way to get that first overlay without using internal APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use undocumented properties, they can (and will) change with any new release of the API.

You need the [overlayMapTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.overlayMapTypes) property,  which is a MVCArray, which has a [getArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#MVCArray.getArray) method

```
window.map.overlayMapTypes.getArray[0]
```